# Keccak256 doesn't return data from mapping

Tags: solidity

Here is a mapping to loans:

```
mapping (uint256 => Loan) public loans;
```

I then use: `uint256(keccak256(abi.encode(address(msg.sender), tokenId)));` to create a unique `loanId` from a struct.

```
 function onERC721Received(
        address,
        address from,
        uint256 tokenId,
        bytes calldata
    )
        external
        override
        returns(bytes4)
    {
        uint256 loanId = uint256(keccak256(abi.encode(address(msg.sender), tokenId)));
        loans[loanId] = Loan({
            nftContract: ERC721(msg.sender),
            tokenId: tokenId,
            borrower: from,
            repayable: false
        });

        // lend(from);
        return 0x150b7a02;
    }
```

Now, to access my a loan, I retrieve the unique id with the following fuction:

```
    function getLoanId(address _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenId) public pure returns (uint256) {
      return uint256(keccak256(abi.encode(address(_tokenContract), _tokenId)));
    }
```

However, the id the `keccak256` spits out doesn't return any data from my mapping. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works just fine. make sure your arguments are correct when you call `getLoanId()'.

you could possibly be confusing the `_tokenContract` argument with that of the  NFT contract and not the `msg.sender`